# Выбор gui c++

Tags: gui, gtk, qt, c++

Встала задача сделать простое приложение с 6 кнопками. Очень нежелательны большие библиотеки. Подскажите какая gui библиотека наиболее минималистична, проста и имеет нужный функционал (Настройка вида виджетов).

Comment: Какая ось?

Comment: Таки С++ Builder подойдет...

Comment: хех, с++ быдлер легким движением руки превратился в библиотеку виджетов. там есть, но ни разу не минималистичная и гвоздями приколочена к винде к тому же.

Comment: вообще кроссплатформенно нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите FLTK, может понравится.

Comment: Плюсую, если нужна минималистичность, скорость, минимальный объем, то FLTK - самое оно. Не знаю, как сейчас, но года четыре назад они практиковали статическую линковку. Темы в FLTK2 вроде тоже есть.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте QT. Для начинающих очень даже несложно. Тем более если 6 кнопок

Comment: Хмм попробуем, хотя qt мне кажется громоздким для такой мелкой задачт

Comment: Qt достаточно универсален, как в решении мелких задач, так и  достаточно крупных проектов. Мои рекомендации.

Comment: Я люблю Qt и сам много пишу с использованием этого фреймворка, но требованиям топикстартера не удовлетворяет, ибо не минималистичен ни разу.

Answer (score 0):

> Используйте QT. Для начинающих очень даже несложно. Тем более если 6 кнопок

я неспорю Qt конечно очень мощный, но если писать на нем то даже простое окно будет весить 10МБ, не так уж и минималистично

Comment: Это наверное в винде. В лине около 30 килобайт (говорю только про окошки).

Comment: да винде, а в лине это из-за того что дллки Qt идут вместе с DE, например с KDE

Comment: Угу, в линуксе тоже метров 10, если разделяемые библиотеки посчитать. А автору нужна именно минималистичность. Возможно, какая-то embedded система. Странно, что минусуют.